# ClickOnce configuration

Tags: clickonce

Had these questions in mind..

1. How is clickonce always downloading the files to the same folder path in windows?
2. How is clickonce creating an application reference (.appref-ms file) in Start Menu?

Is there any code or configuration written anywhere in clickonce for these 2 things to happen?
Or is it internal to clickonce?

Answer (score 0):

it is internal to click once framework - nothing you should do about it

Comment: does microsoft have any documentation specifying this is internal to clickonce? -- just for a confirmation..

Comment: I'm not aware, but searching MSDN should not be a too complex task for you